# What Kinds of Gas Giants Would Work Best in Orbiting an Orange-Dwarf Binary?

Tags: science-based, planets, solar-system, gas-giants

The term "gas giant" is, surprisingly, not uniform.  It turns out that there are far more to the gas giants than Jovian or Saturnian.  I won't list you all of them, just those that I find personally appealing for the question:

- **Puffy planets**:  These are giants that are so hot that they get wider in diameter yet lighter in mass than Jupiter.  (Example:  Kepler-7b)
- **Super-Jupiter**:  These are giants that, true to the title, are far larger than Jupiter.  Any heavier than 80 Jovian masses, and they'd be brown dwarves, not planets.  However, due to compression from the extra mass, they can't get any wider in diameter.  (Example:  Kappa Andromedae b)
- **Class I gas giants (Ammonia clouds)**:  These are where we'd find our gas giants, Jupiter and Saturn.  In a solar system consisting of one yellow dwarf like our sun, these planets would reflect as much as 57% of that star's light.  (Jupiter reflects 34.3%, Saturn 34.2%.)
- **Class II gas giants  (Water Clouds)**:  These are gas giants in which the atmosphere consists of water vapor.  If either of our gas giants are Class II, then they'd reflect an average of 81% of the sun's light.
- **Class III gas giants  (Cloudless)**:  These are gas giants that are so hot (170-980 degrees Fahrenheit) that clouds can't form, appearing as featureless, azure-blue globes.  If this were Jupiter or Saturn, it would reflect only 12% of the sun's light (the same albedo as our own moon.)

In this solar system, the center is a binary of orange dwarves, each one 85% as wide, 78% as massive and only 40% as bright as our sun.  The stars orbit each other from a distance of over 24 million miles.  This creates a habitable zone set from 0.8 to 1.52 AUs from the two orange suns, which means that almost 67 million miles of space have the right conditions for liquid surface water to form.  In that habitable zone are three gas giants orbited by a certain number of co-orbiting Earth-like moons.  (*How many of those moons depends on the answer.*)

Now, using the details described and listed above, **which of these gas giants would work best in orbiting this binary of orange suns from within their habitable zone?**

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: That's a rather vague question.

Comment: Define “work best.”

Comment: "Which of these gas giants would work best": for what purpose? *"One fine day a tiny laddie came and asked his dad: Could you tell me, Daddy, what is good and what is bad? All his daddy said, I heard. Children, gather near. Daddy’s answer, word for word, I shall tell you here."* (Vladimir Mayakovsky, [*What is good and what is bad*](https://archive.org/details/WhatIsGoodAndWhatIsBad-Eng-V.Mayakovsky), English translation by D. Rottenberg, Moscow, 1971. Link goes to Archive.org.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question practically answers itself.  If the gas giant is "too hot", the moons are "too hot".  That leaves the other three.  Now, recently I've been focusing on people inhabiting the *gas giant*, but if you're talking *moons*, then we can take our cues from [Sudarsky's gas giant classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudarsky_extrasolar_planet_classification) which you quote.  Ammonia is too cold, cloudless is too hot (excluded before - though I suppose you can argue the gas giant has internal heat that the moon isn't affected by so much), and alkali metals and silicate clouds are, shall we say, *right out*.  Water moon, water clouds, liquid water habitable zone ... almost done.

Just one detail: the super-Jupiters.  Or mass in general.  There we need the [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit) on one hand and the [Hill sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere) on the other.  The planet has to be heavy and the moon close enough that the suns can't pull the moon away, but the moon can't be so close it gets ripped apart.  Though *almost* ripping it apart makes for iconic science fiction, it might also make for an Io-like uninhabitable moon, so pick your course carefully.

Roche limit (rigid) is apparently (2 D/d)^(1/3)*R, where R is the radius of the gas giant, D is the density of the gas giant, and d is the density of the moon.  Arguably you should use the fluid formula 2.44 (D/d)^(1/3)*R because any decent Earth-oid planet has plate tectonics and a deformable mantle that will change over time.  Note density varies from 0.69 for Saturn to 1.3 g/cm^3 for Jupiter to 13-80 times that of Jupiter (as you observed) for brown dwarves, though I don't think we can count them.  So maybe 17 g/cm^3 or so.  And the moon's density is going to be like 5 for Earth, maybe a few above or below.  From the fluid formula I get that the planet needs to be Saturn's radius again out from it - but Saturn's moons are all further out than this (60000 km doubled).  I'm not sure if I missed something or if the density of Earth would allow it to be fine where there is only ring material for ice moons of Saturn.  But that inner limit could be increased around the cube-root-of-27-fold (3-fold) for a very heavy gas giant - 240,000 km!

That leaves Hill sphere.  Semimajor axis * (m/3M)^(1/3).  Your semimajor axis is quite large, and your planets heavy, and the more they need it for the Roche limit the more they have Hill sphere to work with, so I don't think it's an issue, though I don't have the masses to plug in.

Bottom line: I think you need to see water in the giant planet's atmosphere, but its size is pretty much up to you (if you can find a near brown dwarf that is cool enough, that is - the heat of formation is considerable).  Unless you're worried about the entire three-body system (stars and gas giant) becoming unstable...